# Reverse engineering iOS weather app UI components

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uiscrollview

I am trying to write down a summary of the iOS weather App. The main components that I am interested are labelled in the image below as 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

[image]

The UI should be obtained as following:

A ViewController with:

- 1 - is a UILabel
- 2 - is a UIButton that changes either text or gets hidden to display a 2nd button
- 3 - UIScrollView with horizontal scroll? I guess it has custom cell types.
- 4 - Same as above but vertical cells.

And a PageView controller (5).

Storyboard creation (would like to follow [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)):

- 1-4 - belong to the same ViewController
- 5 - is above this hierarchy.

**Doubts:**

- Is my interpretation correct?
- Are 3/4 vertical view controllers?
- Is there any disadvantage in implementing this using interface/story builder?

Comment: You're going to have difficulty doing some of the fancy animations / parallaxing with storyboards.

Comment: @IanMacDonald thanks! I come from Cocos2D so I prefer doing things programmatically. Your comment sets me in this direction for standard iOS/UIKit too then :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I go on, I should state the obvious: the Weather app is closed source! As such all of this is educated guesswork.

*Is my interpretation correct?*
Not entirely. My guess is that both 3 and 4 are not vanilla `UIScrollView`s, but are instead probably [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html)s. That makes horizontal scrolling (for 3) easy as well as layout and totally custom cells. Also, I suspect that 3 is a subview of 4, because it scrolls up and down with the content of 4.

You'll notice that 1 and 2 move in the same direction as 3 and 4 when scrolled, but not the same speed. This means it's probably a driven animation associated with callbacks from the 4 scroll view.

*Are 3 and 4 vertical view controllers?*
Probably not. Using child view controllers here would be overkill in my opinion.

*Is there any disadvantage in implementing this using interface builder/storyboards?*
Yes. I would definitely not recommend that. These behaviors are rather custom, and I guarantee that you'll eventually find yourself forced to write a fair amount of layout and animation code. If you start with storyboarding, you'll end up with two sources of truth, so to speak, so I just wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thans a lot for the answer. I will try develop on it tomorrow and then most likely accept it. I appreciate ur comment on interface builder. I was under the impression that things were easier programmatically as I can more easily handle the sub view stack (E.g. for background image). Your answer confirms it may be the way to go. Any articles/good reference in this regard/direction? When is actually best to use interface builder? For small/simple apps? I kind of like/prefer doing things programmatically..

Comment: At a (very) high level, I find IB is only useful for apps that do not have a lot of custom UI behavior. It simply cannot help with you with detailed custom UI work, like working with `CALayers` or unusual layout constraints. I happen to have very good reason to believe that Apple does not use it at all, internally. But I recommend you do your own research: Google "should I use storyboards?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sharing your experience.