# Standard Weather app: view hierarchy with same behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to understand, how I can achieve same vertical scroll behavior (all horizontal behavior looks obvious) like in standard Weather iPhone app. I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175238/reverse-engineering-ios-weather-app-ui-components) question, but it's not enough. The goal is to construct view hierarchy using `UIScrollView`'s and/or `UITableView`'s possibly without much custom animations. I made screenshots for three different states:

---

**Initial state:**

[image]

---

**"Refresh" state (dragged):**

[image]

---

**Detail state (scrolled):**

[image]

Ideas that I already have: separate screen to Red, Yellow, Green and Blue modules looks like nice idea.

1) Green + Blue area (and Yellow?) is very close to `UITableView` with Green module as header view, but one unstandard thing - we can move Green module to top, skipping "refresh" area.

2) Even in very top of Red area we can interact with Blue/Green modules, move them up and down, so, possibly this area is `inset` of `UITableView` with custom animated `UIView` under `UITableView`?

Comment: are you looking for the same behavior?

Comment: We cannot know whether they are using a UITableView or a UIScrollView inside the horizontal UIScrollView, but either way, they are updating the tableview cells or subviews of uiscrollview based on the location that the user has scrolled to

Comment: @ShadowOf Is this just a coding request or do you have some code already? If you don't have a specific problem with existing code that's trying to give you the look in the screenshots above, then this question is too broad.

Comment: @TylerH I don't have any code yet. I don't even understand from which UI elements I need to start. __Ideas__ are welcome here

Comment: I have created demo app on [GItHub](https://github.com/dattatraya-anarase/WeatherApp-UI-iOS). Check it out! It doesn't cover all, but almost!

Answer (score 1):

We have no way of really knowing whats going on since it's Apple's source. However there are not a lot of options available to design the kind of logic the weather app has therefore we can assume their process involved steps similar to these.

*You will be writing a fair amount of layout and animation code to get the views moving at different speeds, custom layouts and other fine details.

- First of all you will most likely need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` to get your ***multidirectional scrolling*** and create custom layouts. Subclassing will allow for total control of design of the collection. If you are ok with designing something less complex you might be able to design your collection-based layout with minimal development using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

[Collection View Programming Guide for iOS - Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)

### Feasible Development Outline

1. Building a Custom Layout

   - Populating the CollectionView
   - Subclass `UICollectionViewCell` for managing outlet connections
2. Building custom Layout to hold dynamic data

   - create a `CustomCollectionViewLayout` and have it subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` to provide the collectionView with information on cells. This layout only provides the collection view with information to show to the user. Meaning it won't be part of your UI.

### UICollectionViewLayout

[UICollectionViewLayout Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/)

Every layout object should implement the following methods to conform to protocol:

`collectionViewContentSize`
`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`
`layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`
`shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`